# Android 4.0 emulator can not be launched if set RAM size over 1024

Tags: android, android-emulator, ram

After I create an emulator under android sdk 4.0 with default WXGA800 configuration shown as below :

- Abstracted LCD density : 160
- Keyboard lid support : no
- **Max VM aplication heap : 48**
- **Device ram size : 1024**

it's failed to launch the emualtor after clicking "Start", and there isn't any error/exception prompt. It seems starting AVD doesn't make sense.

But if i change the Device ram size from **1024** to **768**, the emulator can be successfully launched. Is there any limitation on ram size setting according to PC hardware?

I'm using *Windows 7 64bit Ultimate with i3 2.53GHZ , 4GB RAM.*

Does anybody have the similar experience or any idea on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Same experience. On Ubuntu and on Windows XP

Comment: happening to me too on win xp. any solution yet?

Comment: Are there even any android devices out there with more than 1GB of ram?

Comment: i have same problem. i read all pages about this issue on internet, but there is not good and sharp solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the latest ADT v22, it'll show :

```
On Windows, emulating RAM greater than 768M may fail depending on the system load. 
Try progressively smaller values of RAM if the emulator fails to launch
```

when you add RAM more than 768M.

May be the virtualization in Windows doesn't support 1024M RAM.

P.S. Try using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). Its fast, runs on Oracle VM, has GPS,Battery emulation and pre-rooted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common problem when setting up the AVD that you have to manually edit the config file to fix. File is located at C:\Documents and Settings\username.android\avd\name_of_avd.avd\config.ini

Change the memory settings from

hw.ramSize=1024
to

hw.ramSize=1024MB
(Do not enable word wrap in notepad).

Save the file and reopen the avd. This worked for me.